# Why is Kivy drawing Triangle on canvas for only the last button created?

Tags: python, canvas, kivy

I am running Kivy 2.0.0rc3 on Ubuntu with python 3.8.3.  I am trying to draw a triangle on multiple buttons.  The triangle will only show up on the last button added to the layout.  I have tried drawing on the canvas using both kvlang and python code, and both yield the same results.  I have posted the code below.

How can I make Kivy draw the triangle on every button added to the layout?  Thank you in advance.

```
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.graphics import Color, Triangle
from kivy.lang import Builder


KV = """
<TriangleButton>:
    canvas:
        Color:
            rgba: (1, 0, 0, 1)
        Triangle:
            points: [self.width / 3, self.height / 3, 2 / 3 * self.width, self.height / 3, self.width / 2, 2 / 3 * self.height]
"""

Builder.load_string(KV)


class TriangleButton(Button):
    pass
    
    # I have also tried the method below 
    # which yields the same results
    # def __init__(self, **kwargs):
    #     super().__init__(**kwargs)
    #     self.bind(pos=self.update_canvas)
    #     self.bind(size=self.update_canvas)
    #     self.update_canvas()
    #
    # def update_canvas(self, *args):
    #     self.canvas.after.clear()
    #     with self.canvas.after:
    #         Color(1, 0, 0)
    #         Triangle(points=[
    #             self.width / 3, self.height / 3,
    #             2 / 3 * self.width, self.height / 3,
    #             self.width / 2, 2 / 3 * self.height
    #         ])


class MyApp(App):
    def build(self):
        w = BoxLayout(orientation='vertical')
        w.add_widget(TriangleButton())
        w.add_widget(TriangleButton())
        return w


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = MyApp()
    app.run()
```

Here is the Kivy log info.

```
[INFO   ] [Logger      ] Record log in /home/michael/.kivy/logs/kivy_20-09-27_37.txt
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] v2.0.0rc3, git-20c14b2, 20200615
[INFO   ] [Kivy        ] Installed at "/home/michael/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/kivy/__init__.py"
[INFO   ] [Python      ] v3.8.3 (default, Jul  2 2020, 16:21:59) 
[GCC 7.3.0]
[INFO   ] [Python      ] Interpreter at "/home/michael/anaconda3/bin/python"
[INFO   ] [Factory     ] 185 symbols loaded
[INFO   ] [Image       ] Providers: img_tex, img_dds, img_sdl2, img_pil (img_ffpyplayer, img_gif ignored)
[INFO   ] [Text        ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [Window      ] Provider: sdl2
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Using the "OpenGL" graphics system
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Backend used <sdl2>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL version <b'3.0 Mesa 20.0.8'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL vendor <b'Intel Open Source Technology Center'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL renderer <b'Mesa DRI Intel(R) HD Graphics 4000 (IVB GT2)'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] OpenGL parsed version: 3, 0
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Shading version <b'1.30'>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max size <16384>
[INFO   ] [GL          ] Texture max units <16>
[INFO   ] [Window      ] auto add sdl2 input provider
[INFO   ] [Window      ] virtual keyboard not allowed, single mode, not docked
[INFO   ] [ProbeSysfs  ] device match: /dev/input/event4
[INFO   ] [MTD         ] Read event from </dev/input/event4>
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Start application main loop
[WARNING] [MTD         ] Unable to open device "/dev/input/event4". Please ensure you have the appropriate permissions.
[INFO   ] [Base        ] Leaving application in progress...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
points: [self.width / 3, self.height / 3, 2 / 3 * self.width, self.height / 3, self.width / 2, 2 / 3 * self.height]
```

Your declaration of the triangle points fails to take account of the widget position, so all your triangles are drawn in the same place as all the widgets have the same width and height even though they're in different places.

You need to include the pos variables, e.g. the first couple of entries should be `[self.x + self.width / 3, self.y + self.height / 3, ...`.

Comment: I knew it was going to be something simple.  Thank you for the quick and clear answer!